# Android support repository

Tags: android-studio

why after i setup the android studio and when its downloading the files it becomes error when reach android support repository and give me error by retry and never continue 
{

Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 46.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r46.zip

"Install Android Support Repository (revision: 46.0.0)" failed.
can any one tell me what is this and how could i solve it ??

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error when I'm adding the RecyclerView dependency to my gradle file so I downloaded the Android Support Repository from the SDK manager and solved the problem. Here is the link

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

You can follow the instructions there. 
Also pay attention to keep the version of the Repository the same with your local library.